# Strange bug with VS 2012 Winform designer and custom controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, designer, windows-forms-designer

I'm experiencing a strange designer bug in Visual Studio 2012 Designer for winform.

Please note this doesn't happen with VS 2010, neither VS 2014 CTP : only with 2012 !

The bug is the following :

- Assuming I've got a class in a class library which is a direct override of System.Windows.Forms.TextBox (for example). 
  Inside of it, I have added a few properties to meet my needs, and I call it "EnhancedTextBox".

For example :

> ```
> public partial class EnhancedTextBox : TextBox
> {
>     [DefaultValue(false)]
>     [Category("CatBehavior")]
>     [Browsable(true)]
>     [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
>     public bool AllowCaseChanging
>     {
>         get;
>         set;
>     }
> ```

- Assuming now I got a new UserControl which use my "EnhancedTextBox" and sets in design mode its property "AllowCaseChanging".

In VS 2010, everything goes fine. 
But with 2012, I got the following error while opening the UserControl : 
[image: here's what the bug looks like]

If I chose "Ignore and continue", VS removes in .designer.cs every "custom" properties and, hence, mess everything up.

Please note that I can build it well, and there is no problem at runtime : it's only a designer issue.

Target framework : 4, VS 2012 with every updates under Windows 8 (everything up to date AFAIK).

My example applies to a specific case, but in fact I'm experiencing exactly the same problem for all controls in my project which are defining new properties made to be designer-visible. It's also the case for all custom events.

It looks like VS2012 doesn't see my properties and events, only these coming from the "base" control, in my example TextBox.

Comment: There is no getter for the property.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla > sorry, just a typo in code sample. But getter is there, and as I've said the problem also occurs for events.

Comment: The `...` in your getter and setter is actually a very important piece of information. If you've got some side effects going on in there, then yeah the designer will blow up.

Comment: @Richard: I don't confirm your issue. A simplest solution, a class library with your code only and a windows forms application referencing the library. The designer works like a charm and lets me change the value of your property. Windows 7 + VS2012. I am for helrich's comment - you probably do something else than the presented code.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but unfortunately the "..." was just subscribing/unsubscribing an handler to an event. But it's just for THIS case, as I told EVERY custom properties in all my overriden controls based on winform controls, or events handlers (hence with no code behind) raise the same error on designer with VS2012 on this computer. And as I told the same code is ok with 2010 and 2014, which makes the problem even more strange... Even if everything seems to be up to date (according windows update / nuget) i'm thinking to a bug related to installation... anyway, Thanks for your help!